# Core data Fetch request with predicate swift 3

Tags: core-data, swift3, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I know how to fetch from core data with predicates using a 
**let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "MyEntityAttribute == %@", "Matching Value")**. I want to know if it's possible to fetch all of the values for a particular attribute without using a Matching Value. I want to get a count of the total number of values for a particular attribute.

This is what I got so far, but I am only getting back what is matching the **name attribute**.

```
let filter = "wayne"

  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Likes>(entityName: "Likes")
  let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", filter)
  fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {
        let nameCount = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if nameCount.count >= 0 {

            print("name exist")
        }

    }  catch{

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach and use NSFetchRequestResult to get back the result of the single attribute.

```
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Likes")
    fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name"] // Single attribute I wanted to fetch
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
    do {

        let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        let resultDic = result as! [[String:String]]
        print(resultDic.count)

        print(resultDic)

    }  catch{

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
```